# Getting Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String] with Turbo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, bluebird

Note: Turbo uses react/redux

I am using Turbo which you can find out more about here https://www.turbo360.co/

I am getting the `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]` I haven't worked on this project in about a week and I did not have the warning then. I opened it today and all of a sudden I did.

I do not directly use bluebird, I use the turbo library for my actions which return a promise. In all of my promises if I am not using the data in the `then` block then I do a `return null`, If I am using the data then it is just an `alert` of something like `Sucess`. In the `catch` block I just `console.log(err)` or `alert(err)`.

This happens when the app loads so I will post the promises that are called when the app loads just for clarification

```
    if (this.props.post.all == null) {
      this.props
        .fetchPosts({})
        .then(response => {
          return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
    if (this.props.reply.all == null) {
      this.props
        .getReplies({})
        .then(() => {
          return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

  if (this.props.user.currentUser == null) {
      this.props
        .currentUser()
        .then(data => {
          return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

These are the three promises used when the application loads.

Comment: Is any of the `catch` clauses firing?

Comment: No I only have a console log of the warning

Comment: And if you take out these promise chains does it still warn you?

Comment: Yes, Still getting the warning

Comment: Then this isn't related to this code at all.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed something, I opened another project and now im getting the same warning, is this a bluebird bug?

Comment: It's just a warning, at some point you must be throwing something that isn't an error. You can pretty much throw anything, not just error objects. [Bluebird lets you catch only certain type of errors and rethrow everything else](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/2.x#expected-and-unexpected-errors), that's why it encourages you to only reject promises with error objects.

Comment: Yes, but in my other project I do directly use Bluebird and the only time I reject is if the mongo db throws an error. This project was working yesterday just fine, I know for sure. And now I am getting the exact same warning in a completely separate project that was not appearing in either of them, I don't think it is my code at this point.

Comment: It could be that you are using bluebird to replace the global `Promise` constructor. If that's the case any other library that creates promises will end up using bluebird implementation and they might not follow the same guidelines for it. It's best if you don't touch the `Promise` global (look at `Promise.noConflict` in bluebird docs)

Comment: Mmm well it is a very small application and I did a `const Promise = require('bluebird');` and only used it once by doing `return new Promise...`. Maybe this is now conflicting with the js Promise?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I just tried it out from `npm` and that warning isn't on by default. So maybe at some point you added `Promise.config({ warnings: true })` or some other new library that you included did.

Comment: Warnings can also be enabled if you do `NODE_ENV='development'`. Either way, printing the warnings isn't the real problem. You'd ideally want to find out where you rejecting with non-error objects. You'll need the `--trace-warnings` option when running node to find out where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158020/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-minusfour).

Comment: Of course it can happen that one of the libraries you are using does reject its promises with strings.